# Questões arquiteturais de validação

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Estava pensando a respeito de como a validação é aplicada em diferentes cenários e principalmente usando a arquitetura em camadas e me deparei com algumas questões que gostaria de discutir.

Existem validações que devem ser usadas em nível de aplicação e não de negócio? Se existem, então elas não deveriam ser forçadas nas entidades e sim na camada de aplicação acima.

Ao encontrarmos erros na validação como devemos propagar esses erros para as camadas superiores?

1) Criar um tipo específico de Exception (EValidationException) ? E partir disso as camadas superiores poderiam criar código para interceptar e exibir as mensagens de erro?

```delphi
try
    customerService.registerCostumer(name, phoneNumber, email);
except
    on E:EValidationException do
        Self.ShowValidationMessages(E.getErrorMessages());
end;
```

2) Criar um tipo de Application Context que seria injetado nos Application Services e serviria como ponte para erros de validação?

```delphi
validator := TValidator.Create;
//in service layer
if validator.isValid(customer) then
   FApplicationContext.addMessages(validator.getErrorMessages());

//in presentation layer (a form for example)
if applicatioContext.hasErrorMessages() then
    Self.ShowValidationMessages(applicationContext.getErrorMessages());
```

Vou ressaltar que estou desenvolvendo em Delphi e meu projeto usa uma arquitetura em camadas como as camadas do DDD (Não estou usando DDD 100% ainda, apenas uso algumas idéias). Nesse caso estou chamando meu código de validação nos application services.

Answer (score 2):

Como toda ação da aplicação reflete de algum modo na camada de negócios, e que por segurança a validação deve ser realizada ao menos na camada de negócios, não vejo como uma validação possam se restringir à camada de aplicação. Até porque, suas regras são definidas em uma ou mais camadas de negócio.

Suas duas soluções para retornar os erros às camadas superiores da aplicação são válidas. No entanto, acredito que a primeira solução é mais apropriada na maioria dos casos.

Sua segunda opção gera mensagens de erro voltadas ao usuário no mesmo nível que os problemas surgem. Ao meu ver, isto reduz a coesão das camadas, uma vez que uma camada mais interna esta gerando informações que são inerentes de camadas superiores (interface com o usuário não é de responsabilidade da camada de negócios, por exemplo).

Já a primeira opção, é mais coesa e não aumenta o acoplamento mais do que a segunda opção. A comunicação de erro é então realizada através de uma estrutura que permite descrever o erro e suas condições de uma maneira mais fácil de ser manipulada em código. Assim, a camada de aplicação pode gerar a mensagem mais apropriada.

Comment: Nesse caso específico eu mostrei somente o caso em que uso as validações a nível de aplicação, mas também tenho validações a nível de negócio.   

O que eu quis dizer é que existem validações que só existem a nível de aplicação. Em determinada aplicação restrinjo a idade do cliente no mínimo 18 anos e em outras não preciso dessa restrição. Se eu forçar no domínio, terei que modificar a classe para usar em outra aplicação.

Comment: E o outro ponto eu estava mesmo querendo encontrar a melhor maneira de retornar os erros de validação para as camadas superiores. Porque eu não queria ter que colocar um retorno no método do serviço com mensagens de erro de validação, ficaria sem sentido. Vou aplicar a primeira opção mesmo com exceptions então.

Comment: @RobsonCoutinho eu entendi corretamente... talvez eu tenha me enrolado e não deixado claro hehehe... No caso da restrição dos 18 anos, o correto é validar no modelo de negócios também. Como esta construindo em Delphi, é improvável que o usuário drible sua validação na camada de aplicação, mas no caso de uma aplicação web, este é um caso que deve ser levado a sério. Não sei como construiu exatamente sua aplicação, mas talvez utilizar o Decorator Pattern seja o mais apropriado, mas provavelmente te forçará a algumas modificações de baixo nível na apliacação.